# Indentation after a title using `alternative=text`

Tags: indentation, context

I am using ConTeXt 2018.04.04 from TeXLive 2018.
When I use the `alternative=text` option in `\setuphead`, the second paragraph after the title is not indented.
I cannot find in the manual how to get it indented.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\setupindenting[yes,big]
\setuphead[section][alternative=text]
\starttext
\section{Introduction}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

When I add the following option, it does not change anything:

```
\setuphead[section][alternative=text,indentnext=yes]
```

In the example, I want the paragraph beginning with

> The separation of any...

to be indented, but it isn't.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem also appears in the latest beta.  Apparently the problem was introduced when fixing another bug, because commenting the line

```
\noindentation % recently added, was a bug
```

in `\strc_rendering_stop_placement` fixes the problem.  This has been reported on the mailing list: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/094251.html

```
\unprotect

\def\strc_rendering_stop_placement
  {\n_strc_rendering_hang_lines\zerocount
   \ifconditional\headisdisplay
     \strc_rendering_initialize_line_hang
     % kind of special, we want to snap heads also according to local specs local
     \setbox\b_strc_rendering_head\hbox
       {\hskip\dimexpr\d_strc_rendering_local_leftoffset+\headparameter\c!margin\relax
        \box\b_strc_rendering_head
        \getheadsyncs % a latelua why not in the box
        }%
     \ifgridsnapping
       \applygridmethod
         {\headparameter\c!grid}%
         {\ifconditional\headisdisplay
            \strc_rendering_initialize_style_and_color_display\c!textstyle\c!textcolor
          \fi}%
         {\box\b_strc_rendering_head}
     \else
       \box\b_strc_rendering_head
     \fi
     \flushnotes % new, not really needed
     \endgraf
     \ifvmode
       \ifnum\n_strc_rendering_hang_lines>\zerocount
         \dorecurse\n_strc_rendering_hang_lines{\nointerlineskip\dosomebreak\nobreak\strut\endgraf}% to be checked
       \fi
       \nointerlineskip
       \dosomebreak\nobreak
     \fi
%      \getheadsyncs % a latelua why not in the box
   \else
     % somehow this goes ok even when we push in the margin probably because we gobble pars
     % in the process of collecting index entries etc
     \strut
     \flushnotes % new, here since we're in par mode
     \unhbox\b_strc_rendering_head
     \getheadsyncs % a latelua
     \ifconditional\headissomewhere
       \strc_sectioning_stay_on_this_line % test case: alternative=margintext and \startparagraph ..
     \else
      %\hskip\headnumberdistance\s!plus\headnumberdistance\s!minus.25\dimexpr\headnumberdistance\relax
       \hskip\headtextdistance\relax
       \strc_sectioning_inject_continuous_signal
     \fi
   \fi
   \ifconditional\headisdisplay
     \ifvmode
       \ifgridsnapping % important, font related depth, see comment
         \prevdepth\strutdp
       \else
         \prevdepth\d_strc_rendering_local_depth
       \fi
     \fi
   \fi
   \synctexpopline
   \egroup
   \egroup
   \ifconditional\headisdisplay
     \useindentnextparameter\headparameter
   \else
     \ignoreparskip
     % \noindentation % recently added, was a bug
   \fi}

\protect

\setupindenting[yes,big]
\setuphead[section][alternative=text,indentnext=yes]
\starttext
\section{Introduction}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: This kind of redefinition looks like a use case for some `xpatch` or `etoolbox` type of patching functionality, is anything like that available or planned for ConTeXt?

Comment: @Marijn No, there is no such thing for ConTeXt, because in contrast to most LaTeX packages, ConTeXt is actually actively being developed which means that bugs are fixed as soon as they are reported, making all the weird patching business superfluous.

Comment: Case in point: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-context/2019/003551.html